# как скачать сайт python-ом

Tags: python

Существует ли какая-нибудь библиотека, чтобы скачать сайт в файл?

Как если бы я просто вручную зашел на сайт и нажав правой кнопкой мыши и выбрал:
"Сохранить как...".

PS urllib не нужно предлагать

Comment: Ну что ж, скопировать сайт целиком это уже давно не проблема, надо лишь выбрать подходящий для себя способ. А их три:

Открывать каждую страничку и сохранять на диск
Использовать онлайн-сервисы
Пользоваться специальными программами Источник: <a href="https://it-like.ru/kak-skachat-sayt-polnostyu/">https://it-like.ru/kak-skachat-sayt-polnostyu/</a>

Comment: `requests` https://pypi.org/project/requests/2.7.0/

Answer (score 2):

Библиотека requests - ваше решение.

Ниже пример использования с сохранением титульной страницы Википедии в файл:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://ru.wikipedia.org')
file = open('wiki.html', 'w')
file.write(r.text)
file.close()
```

[Страничка на PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)